# RCU consumption if DynamoDB item not found

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

On querying a Dynamodb table with a hashkey, if no items exist, then what is the RCU consumption? And if such calls are made on a frequent basis, can it lead to problem of hot partitioning?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't have items, you will still consume RCU's. The amount will depend on the type of read request you use (ie: eventually consistent, strongly consistent or transactional), and the size of the item you're returning. See aws docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html) for more info, with the main point being:

> If you perform a read operation on an item that does not exist, DynamoDB still consumes provisioned read throughput

To get a bit more detailed about [how different read operations affect the consumed rcus for missing items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html):

> One read request unit represents one strongly consistent read request, or two eventually consistent read requests, for an item up to 4 KB in size ... For example, if your item size is 8 KB, you require 2 read request units to sustain one strongly consistent read, 1 read request unit if you choose eventually consistent reads, or 4 read request units for a transactional read request

the key phrase in the above is *up to 4KB*. So you don't necessarily have to have data to consume RCU's by that logic.

As far as your question about hot partitioning, you will run into that problem if you have an unequally distributed access pattern (ie: you have non-uniform bursts of read/write requests for the same hash key). However, dynamodb has [adaptive capacity](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) in place to scale individual partitions to avoid throttling. They mention:

> In this post, we explain why capacity and provisioning in DynamoDB are no longer concerns. To do this, we first cover the basics of how DynamoDB shards your data across partitions and servers. Then, we highlight a feature called adaptive capacity that corrects the nonuniform workload issues that you might have experienced in the past

Comment: To clarify, if the hash key itself is invalid, then can it lead to a problem of hot partitioning? I believe as hash key is invalid, it should not belong to any partition.

Comment: @mosalah would you mind clarifying what you mean by the hash key being "invalid"?

Comment: I mean there exists no item with the given hashkey.